# How to display motd when starting a new shell

Tags: bash, shell, motd

What parameters can be passed to the bash shell so that it displays the motd?

Shouldn't `bash -l` display the motd?

Answer (score 2):

No, `bash -l` does not display the Message of the Day.  From `motd(5)`'s manual page:

> NAME
>          motd - message of the day
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          The contents of /etc/motd are displayed by pam_motd(8) after a successful login but just before it executes the login shell.

To have your shell do it, add `cat /etc/motd` to your profile or shell rcfile.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16 and am using a dynamically generated motd that changes, so when I ssh in I can see a different motd every time but if I just cat the motd file it doesn't change unless I ssh in again.

Comment: As I said, that's presented by PAM, not your shell.   In this case, for details, check `man update-motd`.

Comment: Dynamically created motd may add latency to your login that is undesirable.

Comment: Since Ubuntu's out-of-the-box MOTD is _already_ dynamic, I don't think that would be too much of a concern in this case.